# CDI Transactions warnings

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

after calling a method, which is working with database (JPA) I am getting warnings:

```
@Named    
public class SomeClass{
    
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpaLayer")
private EntityManager entityManager;
        .....
        .....
    @Transactional
    public T save(T entity) {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            return entity;
    }
}
```

***Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED called outside a transaction context.  Beginning a transaction...***

But then its generating SQL query and everything is OK.

*Info:   Hibernate: insert into ALL_USERS_EXMPL (DATE_ADDED, login, password) values (?, ?, ?)*

How can I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REQUIRES_NEW` instead of `REQUIRED` to run it outside a transaction context.
Please refer to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html)

you need to have `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: thank you, but now, every time i call the method, server prints messages "In REQUIRES_NEW TransactionalInterceptor" - can i turn off them ?

Comment: you need to set that in your log configuration for that package, the threshold level for any package can be set in your logs with log4j.